# CS Cart to Magento 2 user password migration

Tags: php, magento, md5, cs-cart

We have a CS Cart and a Magento 2 website and now we want to migrate all customers from CS Cart store to Magento 2. Rest of the things are fine for us but password is the problem. We want to migrate password also from CS Cart to Magento 2 so that user can login to this new Magento site with same credentials which they were using in CS Cart.

But because both systems use their own hashing method (CS Cart uses MD5 with some salt sufix) so direct migration of password hash does not work.

How we can migrate all user accounts from CS Cart to Magento 2 with passwords?

Answer (score -1):

Simple, just import all the users with their passwords and salts like this: 'password|salt' and hook into the password check function.

In PHP check if the '|' character is in the string, explode it, generate the password, if it matches, you also update the user password by putting it in the magento password generation function.

Comment: hi @Subjective how to generate the password for magento2 from opencart password+salt ?